# ASP.NET Core: request returns 200 OK with no content: controller not instantiated

Tags: .net, f#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core server. My server requests are returning 200 OK, but no content is coming back, and from what I can make out, the controller is not even being instantiated.

The last input from the Azure streaming logs looks like this:

> Application: 2018-07-20 13:42:13.294 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter: Request successfully matched the route with name '(null)' and template 'api/{culture}/NotificationsReceived/{upToUtc}/{take}'.
>   Application: 2018-07-20 13:42:13.670 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLFE8PANI4TL" completed keep alive response.
>   Application: 2018-07-20 13:42:13.670 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 413.5636ms 200

So the route is matched and the request completes, but I have tried attaching breakpoints to the controller (the remote debugger attaches, but no breakpoints are ever hit, even in my middleware), and logging information from the controller as follows:

```
[<Authorize>]
[<Route("api/{culture}/[controller]")>]
type NotificationsReceivedController(notifications: IReceivedNotifications, logger: ILog) =
    inherit Controller()
    do logger.Information "NotificationsReceivedController" "Created controller" None

    [<HttpGet("{upToUtc}/{take}")>]
    [<ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof<PageOfNotifications>)>]
    member this.Get(upToUtc:int64, take:int) =
        async {
            let upToUtc = new DateTime(upToUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            logger.Information "NotificationsReceivedController" "GetReceivedNotifications endpoint" None
            let! notifications = notifications.GetAsync this.HttpContext upToUtc take
            return this.Ok(notifications) :> IActionResult
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

I don't understand the false positive. If something is going wrong in my pipeline, why is it not picked up in the logs? And if nothing is going wrong, why is the route getting matched, but the controller not getting instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using an exception filter

```
type ApiError = {
    ErrorType: Type
    Message: string
    StackTrace: string
}

type ApiExceptionAttribute(logger: ILog) =
    inherit ExceptionFilterAttribute()
    static let [<Literal>] Tag = "ApiExceptionAttribute"
    override __.OnException(context) =
        base.OnException context
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode <-
            match context.Exception with
            | As (_: UnauthorizedAccessException) -> HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized |> int
            | _ -> HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError |> int
        let ex = context.Exception.GetBaseException()
        let apiError = {
            ErrorType = ex.GetType()
            Message = ex.Message
            StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
        }
        logger.Error Tag (apiError.ToString()) (Some ex)
        context.Result <- JsonResult apiError
```

Then, following standard practice, I set this filter as a global filter in my `Startup.fs` file:

in my Startup.fs file:

```
services.AddMvc(fun config -> 
    config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader <- true
    config.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionAttribute>() |> ignore
) |> ignore
```

This solved my false positive and allowed me to track down and fix the errors in my code.